Most curvy rivers?
Missisippi and Amazonas are well known for meandering, but my question is a bit more large-scale. Assume that on a map, you box in the Amazonas into a smallest rectangle. (Exclude all the rivulets that contribute, or the question becomes pointless!) I did it on a Wiki pic...

...and got an aspect ratio of ~8-9. Not that curvy, right?
Of course, the smaller a river, the easier it might "run in circles". Here is an example I googled: The Doubs. Never heard of, so it doesn't count. Aspect ratio ~2-3.

So (arbitrarily) let's just consider rivers >1000 km. Which would be the most curvy with the above definition?

Check out Stølum, H. H. (1996). River meandering as a self-organization process. Science, 271(5256), 1710-1713.  https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.271.5256.1710.  P.S. Rivers that you have never heard of count.

There is already a metric for this, called the sinuosity index: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinuosity#Rivers No need to compute a new one.

@Jean-MariePrival Yes but the OP is asking what river has the highest index along a 1000km reach.

The problem with this question is that when a river gets REALLY twisty you get braiding which makes it impossible to measure the true sinuosity of the reach. Also your terminology is unclear do you mean the windiest river that is over 1000km long in total or the 1000 windiest kms of river in the world?

@Ash I think they mean: which is the most sinuous river (overall) among rivers longer than 1000 km.

@Jean-MariePrival Then see my answer.

For the overall length of the river the Juruá River in the amazon basin seems to take the prize; it has a sinuosity index of 3, over a 1000km down valley distance it covers 3000km of path distance.
That was the highest number I could find and confirm but this article states that sinuosity indices can run as high as 4. I think this is likely to be for shorter reaches such as certain sections of the north fork of the Shenandoah River in Virginia rather than over the full course length like the Juruá value above.

Haven't heard of the term "sinuiosity index" either :-) THX for bringing it to my attention.
